# Variable valve becomes null

Tags: excel, vba

I print data from sql to excel
And in one value of the variable after the first time I've write to the excel is value becomes null.
This is my code:

```
Dim rec as New Recordset
'get the rows from the db
'.
'.
'.
For x = 1 To 13
    Print rec, x
Next

Sub Print(recS as Recordset, row as integer)
    Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Cells(row, 1).Value = recS("a")
'good value in the first time
Cells(row, 2).Value = recS("b")
'the value is null
Debug.Print recS("b")
End Sub
```

There is only one row from the db, and i loop over the row because every time i print some different records from the row. but just record "b" in the first time has value, and right after the first time that I use is value he is becomes null

Comment: Please clarify what "becomes null" specifically stands for: is the worksheet cell blank or it contains the literal string value `NULL`? Or is `recS("a")` a `NULL` value?  Why are you dereferencing the field and its value twice instead of pulling it into a local variable? What is a "good value"? What do you want to output to the worksheet when the db field is `NULL`?

Comment: Also if you're iterating all rows of a recordset to dump them onto a worksheet, consider ditching this approach and using `Range.CopyFromRecordset` instead: there's no need for a loop, no need to `Select` or `Activate` anything or to manipulate any cells or records directly.

Comment: The value of recS("") is null and the cell is empty after the first use. If it was empty or null from the beginning i dont care but just in one value its happens. And i have no reason to put it in local var. I loop the fields because there's field's in the db names size1 size2 etc.. and i want to put one size each row but this field i want to put always